# disabling URL (not to be copied) in firefox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to ask that how could i restrict the user not to copy the URL displayed in firefox. One option is to Disable the URL not to be shown to the user 
other one is to Disable the address bar so that the URL can be seen but cant be copied.

But i dont know how to achieve any of these using javascript.

Any help along with code snippet would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a new window without the address bar using [the `window.open` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.open#Return_value_and_parameters).

But

- certain browsers (think mobile...) don't support hiding the address bar
- users can possibly disable this feature in their  browser settings
- there is always more than one way to copy the URL, not only from the address bar

Answer (score 5):

You have absolutely no control over that portion of browser UI.

This *cannot* be done. Not via javascript, and probably not through any other legitimate means, either.